# Best Ways to prevent change of active record id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, security

When I build a system with different authorization, apart from storing the respective user information inside the active record and check it after submission, are there any good ways to prevent users from changing some critical information (say, record id) inside the form?

(i.e. Users will not be able to change those records not they owned)

Comment: You mean [strong parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)?

Comment: For example, by using default active record mechanism, user can modify the id of active record (in DOM/ URL)  which is not owned by the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @sjagr already in the comments said: You have to use [Strong Parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).

Example:

You have a model `User` with `id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`. The user should only be able to update the first and lastname.

**Your View:**

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :firstname %>
  <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**Your Controller:**

```
before_action :set_user

def edit
end

def create
  if @user.update user_params
     # Set success message
     # redirect to proper site
  else
     # Set error
     render :edit
  end
end


private

def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])    # Rescue against ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname)   # Here the strong parameters stuff happens
end
```

If you want to permit more parameters you just have to add them to the `permit` method call.